# Mac OS, How to run an executable that takes input in vim?

Tags: vim, macvim

In competitive programming, we often have some small input we want to test our C++ program on. I already know of being able to remap some keys to make vim compile and run the executable.

However, I am interested in running the executable inside VIM, and it not appearing at the bottom but in the full VIM display.

More precisely, I want to achieve what is done in the following youtube video at around 2:19:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EQRw-GElS0g&ab_channel=VedantKumud

Comment: It is asking a bit much for someone else to watch a video to answer your question.  It would be more helpful if you took the time and summarised the video with a few screenshots.

Comment: Okay fair enough.

Comment: What you're seeing in that video at around 2:19 is just running a command via the `:!command` syntax. However, there's also `:terminal command` that was introduced in Vim 8.1.

Comment: I see, but the problem is that it does not take the full screen. Do you know how to fix that ?

Comment: Also with the terminal command when we are done giving input it becomes editable, unlike in the video.